# Why use use axios.post request in getInitialProps in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

Hello Guys I am learning NextJs from a tutorial. There is a link to update categories in which the instructor is using axios.post request in getInitialProps. I am confused why not use axios.get request because aren't we using getting the initial props to populate the page. Here is the code

```
Update.getInitialProps = async ({ req, query, token }) => {
  const response = await axios.post(`${API}/category/${query.slug}`);
  return { oldCategory: response.data.category, token };
};

export default withAdmin(Update);
```

I get this error if I use axios.get [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RnO3.jpg)

Comment: Depends on what the API expects. A POST seems weird here, but there's no way for us to know what's expected.

Comment: Server Error
Error: Request failed with status code 404

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
createError
..... I get this erro if I use axios.get

Comment: Okay. Unclear what we're supposed to do with this information; it just means there's no GET route for what looks like should be a GET request. Again: there's no way for us to know what's expected, we didn't write the API.